# Django does not find static on all pages except the main

Tags: python, django

The project is hosted (support say to solve the problem yourself and therefore my friends hope for your help) and you can find it at: https://caparolcenterspb.ru

All styles, pictures and js appear on the main page, but not on other pages. You can see the errors directly in the browser, but just in case I give a screen:
[image]

Comment: Show us the `link` tags in your template.

Comment: Please post your template code.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are adding the path to the static file not from the STATIC_ROOT, but from the current URL. I'll explain with the example. 
On the main page, you got the link:

https://caparolcenterspb.ru/

And looking for the static logo at:

https://caparolcenterspb.ru/static/img/Logo.svg

And all works fine. But if you will go to

https://caparolcenterspb.ru/services/

The URL for the logo request will change to:

https://caparolcenterspb.ru/services/static/img/Logo.svg

Which is wrong and there are obviously no files on this link.

So, the solution to your problem will be fixing STATIC_URL in Django settings. You need to use the same fixed STATIC_ROOT for all static requests and everything will be fine.

It is pretty simple, just check everything is done as it described here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

Comment: It might just be that `STATIC_URL` is set to `static/`, not `/static/`.

Comment: Excuse me, i'm stupid. static_root was '../static/' because of this he searched for the folder static above, apparently I accidentally brought it in and forgot to fix it

Comment: If you find an answer is a solution to your problem, can you mark it as the right one, pls ?

Answer (score 0):

The shown error explains your  MIME is text/html not text/css. It's linked to your browser or OS.
Try to add this in your settings.py:

```
import mimetypes
mimetypes.add_type("text/css", ".css", True)
```